# select to check if a column does not contain a value in a provided array

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to select to check if any of the countries I have in my string array is not contained in the country table in the psql database.

Therefore I have a list of country names ARRAY['Country1','country2'.....]

and I have a table of country and I want a query to select countries that are not in this string that I will provide to the where clause

Something like this

```
  SELECT name from country where name not in (ARRAY['Country1','country2'.....])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
SELECT name 
from country 
where name <> ALL (ARRAY['Country1','country2'.....])
```